# WSO2 - Identity server - How to customize the password reset and recovery screens

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

Is it possible to customize the password reset / recovery or any other screen related to the password scenarios? I added an image below of the current screen. We need to add a different logo and change in the design of the screen. Is this possible?

[image]

Comment: What's the Identity Server version you are currently using?

Comment: @BrionMario latest 6.1.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is possible, You can customize the User Interfaces of authentication/recovery pages.

You can follow these simple steps or you can refer to this [Re-brand WSO2 Identity Server UIs](https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/references/extend/rebranding/rebrand-identity-server-uis/) document as well.

**Step 1 :**
Create a new folder as `extensions` in `<IS_HOME>/repository/deployment/server/webapps/accountrecoveryendpoint`  Folder.

**Step 2 :**

- Copy these files from
  `<IS_HOME>/repository/deployment/server/webapps/authenticationendpoint/includes`folder.

1. header.jsp
2. product-footer.jsp
3. product-title.jsp

- Paste files into `<IS_HOME>/repository/deployment/server/webapps/authenticationendpoint/extensions` folder

**Step 3 :**
Create Styling - Do the required changes to override the existing UI styling.

**Step 4 :**
Edit the existing content
In this step you can replace the contents of the 3 files that were mentioned in ***Step:2***.
Then add the following includes as well.

```
<%@include file=”https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/6.1.0/includes/localize.jsp” %>
<%@include file=”https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/6.1.0/includes/init-url.jsp” %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to update the `accountrecoveryendpoint` as mentioned in [this](https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/references/extend/rebranding/customizable-login-portal/) document. You can create an extensions directory and add the custom styles and assets there.